# Cannot start multiple nodes for RabbitMQ cluster on Windows

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp, rabbitmqctl

I am trying to setup multiple RabbitMQ nodes in Windows environment. Based on the [official guide](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html#single-machine), I am setting up 2 nodes but that's where problem starts to occur.

My first node is successfully created and up and running. But I cannot start 2nd node.

Check below output. ( All the commands are executed from Admin cmd. Erlang and python is also present. All precautionary steps are taken as per guide along with management plugin.)

[image]

You can see above, that my "*hare*" node is running. But second node "*rabbit* " fails to start.

I also replaced cookie as per stack-overflow [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121706/setting-up-rabbitmq-cluster-on-windows-servers) question. Still the problem persists.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone facing similar problem, I changed my approach and was successfully able to run *rabbitmq cluster*.

I moved my cluster to **Linux** and faced no problems. Although it did satisfy my current needs; any solution to above problem is welcome.

Cheers.